# blogger api jquery retrieve blog not post

Tags: jquery, api, blogger

I am able to pull one post at a time from a blog using Jquery:

```
 <div id="content"></div>
              <script>
                    function handleResponse(response) {
                        $("#content").html("<h2>" + response.title + "</h2>" + "<p>" + response.content + "</p>")
                        //document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<h2>" + response.title + "</h2>" + response.content;
                        }
                </script>

                <script
                    src="https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v2/blogs/YourBlogID/posts/3616509663895350385?callback=handleResponse&key=YourAPIKey">
                </script>
```

When I change the call to retrieve the entire BLOG I get "undefined"...

```
<script src="https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v2/blogs/YourBlogID/posts?callback=handleResponse&key=YourAPIKey">
                </script>
```

I just want the NEWEST blog post to show up on the page automatically instead of having to go and switch out the blogID every time.

-->
--thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is due to an "undocumented" change in the Blogger API that has still not been updated in their API documentation (Example, [this page](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/2.0/json/using#WorkingWithPosts) still lists the "content" property as part of the default result set when calling `/posts`). This was likely done at some point to reduce the response size on a default call; they just haven't done a great job of letting developers know that.

The solution is to simply append `fetchBodies=true` to your API call; this will ensure the `content` property is returned for each post. Example:

```
<script src="https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v2/blogs/YourBlogID/posts?callback=handleResponse&key=RemovedForSecurity&fetchBodies=true"></script>
```

Comment: still returning "undefined"

Comment: Have you checked in the browser console to confirm the updated URL I provided returns your data? I did, and it's there :) - because the `posts` endpoint without an ID returns all posts, the resulting JSON has a different structure (i.e. there's a parent object now with an array of posts). You're issue now isn't pulling the data, it's parsing the JSON; have you tried `response.items[0].content` to pull the content for the newest post?

Comment: If possible, you should also consider upgrading to v3.0 of the API. Just for this requirement, and querying posts, the updated version adds `orderBy` & `maxResults` parameters; this would allow you to query for only 1 post and always have it be the most recently published one. The 2.0 API has `maxResults` but no `orderBy`.